# How to Open & Modify an Attribute of a Files' Properties using Python?

Tags: python, properties

I've been having some troubles trying to determine a method in which I can open a files' property window, go to the Details tab and then edit one of the values of a specific value. In more detail, I have over 200 Mp3 files in a folder which I'd like to edit the Number Property Value to an increasing variable. Basically this is my prediction of what it will look like:

```
import os

count = 0
directory = #directory of folder containing x amount of files
files = os.listdir(directory)
for i in files:
    count += 1
    #some code to open up i's property window
    #some code to go to the details tab
    numberProperty = #some code to get the info of the Property's Value
    numberProperty = count
```

Anyways, all the help I can get it mighty appreciated. I look forward to your responses.
*NOTE* I'm running on Windows 7.

Comment: Test, be sure to indent your code four spaces for proper formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) which allows you to modify mp3 ID3 attributes:

```
 import eyeD3
 tag = eyeD3.Tag()
 tag.link("/some/file.mp3")
 print tag.getArtist()
 print tag.getAlbum()
 print tag.getTitle()
 tag.setArtist(u"Cro-Mags")
 tag.setAlbum(u"Age of Quarrel")
 tag.update()
```

Or you could use [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial):

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
audio = EasyID3("example.mp3")
audio["title"] = u"An example"
audio.save()
```

Another option would be to use songdetails (check it out on Github. I can only post 2 hyperlinks):

```
import songdetails
song = songdetails.scan("data/commit.mp3")
if song is not None:
    song.artist = "Great artist"
    song.save()
```

I hope this helped. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your quick and thorough response. I believe this is exactly what I was looking for (haven't had the chance to use yet due to time constraints but it seems to depict what I'm asking for). On a side note, and I know this is very 'beginnerish' sounding but how do I install these files? I'm used to just have a .exe file unpacking them into my Python26 source folder and with these modules, I don't want to overwrite anything. Any help on this is also appreciated.

Comment: Mutagen is included in the binary package available at the [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#base) page. It's a regular Windows installer.

For Songdetails you can download it [here](https://github.com/shiva/songdetails/zipball/master), unzip it somewhere, and then run `python setup.py install` in that directory.